# jQuery to select href with a forward slash in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I have a link
`<a href="foo/bar">example</a>`

and I'm trying to use jQuery to select it via

`$("a[href=foo/bar]")`

but I run into the following error:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=foo/bar]`

Without the `/` this method works fine, however the `/` is there because of the routing in my Backbone app.  I'd prefer to avoid the extra markup of setting id's as this method works for everything else.  Is there any way to select this `<a>` using the href attribute with this slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you're missing the closing single quote. Should be:

`$("a[href='foo/bar']")`

Comment: how is fixing your syntax error and forming a legit selector "irrelevant to the actual issue" ? tis' css3; quotes matter in attrib selectors! seems you can lead a horse to water, but he might kick you into the pond...

Comment: Sorry.  My mistake.  I had tried the single quotes already but I had a different issue that caused the selection to fail.  Thank you @helion3

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes around the href value

```
$("a[href='foo/bar']")
```

Escape it with double backslashes

```
$("a[href=foo\\/bar]")
```

Comment: Using a local test environment, if I run `console.log($("a[href=foo/bar]"));` I get the `Syntax error, unrecognized expression` that Alexander was talking about as opposed to escaping the forward slash, which runs fine.

Here's a screenshot: http://cl.ly/TmFt

Comment: if "runs fine" means not working without throwing; it should be console.log($("a[href='foo/bar']")); which runs even finer in that it doesn't throw and might actually hit some elements...

Comment: `$("a[href=foo/bar]")` doesn't just get thrown—it doesn't work at all. I've edited my answer to accommodate the single quotes around the foo/bar value.

Though not elegant, escaping does work too if you're excluding the single quotes.

Comment: no legit href looks like "blah.com/about\/more", so what's the point of the escaped backslash ?

Comment: It's not about how the "legit" the href looks. It's about how the script properly selects the desired element. I'm not asking him to change the `<a>` href value.

Comment: but that won't select the element in the question without adding a slash to the href that doesn't belong. Why do i get the feeling you haven't actually tested that the code you show does what you claim?

Comment: you're right, sorry. i tried testing it originally, but i must have screwed something else up that time. time for me to hit the specs!